# If you don't set an expiration for a cookie, will it be lost when the browser is closed?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

If you don't set an expiration for a cookie, will it be lost when the browser is closed?

Answer (score 2):

If it has no expiration, then it will.  It will be treated as a Session cookie.  An exception to this are new versions Firefox, which can save your session.

Note, Chrome has a feature that keeps a process open, so closing the browser does not necessarily clear your session. Check your Task Bar for the Chrome icon.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. If you don't set an expiration for a cookie it will be stored only in memory and removed when the session ends. If you do set an expiration, it will be stored on the hard disk.